# Problems with communication between Roboguide and RVIZ

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-industrial, fanuc, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I'm working con ROS-Industrial and with the FANUC m20ia Robot

I'm try running the ROS-Industrial programs on my FANUC simulate called RoboGuide, I follow the instructions that appear in http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/Running, buy I had not success with this.

First I ran the TP program ROSTATE in AUTO mode on RoboGuide and I get the "I RSTA Waiting for ROS state prox" message on displat of Teach Pendant.

Then I run on my Linux PC (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) the

```
roslaunch fanuc_m20ia_support robot_state_visualize_m20ia.launch robot_ip:=172.22.61.233 use_bswap:=false
```

instruction, and appear the RVIZ, but when I tried jogging the robot on RoboGuide, the model of RVIZ don't reflect the same movements. On the terminal I get:

```
romandy@romandy-VirtualBox:~$ roslaunch fanuc_m20ia_support robot_state_visualize_m20ia.launch robot_ip:=172.22.61.233 use_bswap:=false
... logging to /home/romandy/.ros/log/44a16120-50b6-11e5-8c2e-0800271389e3/roslaunch-romandy-VirtualBox-2831.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://romandy-VirtualBox:44066/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /J23_factor: 1
 * /controller_joint_names: ['joint_1', 'join...
 * /joint_state_publisher/source_list: ['my_controller/r...
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_ip_address: 172.22.61.233
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.13

NODES
  /
    joint_state (fanuc_driver/robot_state)
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2847]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 44a16120-50b6-11e5-8c2e-0800271389e3
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2860]
started core service [/rosout]
process[joint_state-2]: started with pid [2877]
process[joint_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [2892]
process[robot_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [2895]
process[rviz-5]: started with pid [2918]
```

After a time, pop out the next massage on the terminal:

```
ERROR 1441118076.606392345: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection timed out' (errno: 110)
ERROR 1441118203.965873915: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection timed out' (errno: 110)
ERROR 1441118203.966035108: Failed to receive message length
ERROR 1441118203.966095454: Failed to receive incoming message
ERROR 1441118336.189696820: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection timed out' (errno: 110)
ERROR 1441118336.189818327: Failed to receive message length
ERROR 1441118336.189858459: Failed to receive incoming message
```

I did some test but I had not success. I hope someone of this community can help.

Yours sincerely, Andres

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216892/problems-with-communication-between-roboguide-and-rviz/) by [andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/23730/andy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ERROR 1441118076.606392345: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection timed out' (errno: 110)
> ```

This seems to suggest that the `fanuc_driver/robot_state` node running on your ROS PC is unable to connect with the `ros_state` program running on your simulated robot controller. I can think of a number of reasons why this could be the case:

1. the IP you provided for `robot_ip` is incorrect: make sure this is the IP of the Windows PC running Roboguide
2. the firewall on the Windows PC does not allow external connections to Roboguide: you'll have to make sure that the `frvirtual.exe` process (which actually runs the virtual controller) is allowed to accept connections on ports 11000 and 11002 from hosts on your network. See [Allow a program to communicate through Windows Firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7) fi on how to do this for Windows 7.

You can use the following command (on your ROS pc) to check whether things would work (without having to use the `robot_state_visualize_m20ia.launch` file):

```
nc ip.of.your.windowspc 11002
```

This should begin to dump a continuous stream of semi-printable data to your terminal (use `ctrl+c` to stop it).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/23730/andy/) on 2015-09-01**:
Uohhh!! I'm very grateful of you, some very simple but definitely I could't wiht this. Very very thanks. The problem was the robot_ip.

Thanks!!

**Comment by [andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/23730/andy/) on 2015-09-01**:
Excuse me, I have other error. Now I can see how the model of RVIZ does the same movements that the model of RoboGuide,but when close the ROS session I get a new error:

**Comment by [andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/23730/andy/) on 2015-09-01**:
^C[rviz-5] killing on exit
[robot_state_publisher-4] killing on exit
[joint_state_publisher-3] killing on exit
[joint_state-2] killing on exit
ERROR 1441141619.565248423: Socket select function failed, rc: -1. Error: 'Interrupted system call' (errno: 4)
[joint_state-2] escalating to SIGTERM

**Comment by [andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/23730/andy/) on 2015-09-01**:
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
romandy@romandy-VirtualBox:~$

**Comment by [andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/23730/andy/) on 2015-09-01**:
I hope you can help me, thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-02**:
In general: please ask new questions in a new question. We can only give you one answer per question (it's how Askbot works).

re: new error: that is not an error. Well it is, but you can ignore it. It simply tells you that the node was shutdown right in the middle of doing something. It's ok.